# Frame Layout fixed elements on wrap_content height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have the next design:

[Actual design app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge7Nh.png)

**CODE:**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/edit_name"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#99000000"
android:weightSum="1">

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@color/tabIndicator"
    android:layout_width="310dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="136dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.75">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/close_circle"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X"
        android:background="@drawable/oval_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|right"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/tabIndicator"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:translationZ="2dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDescLarga"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="208dp"
        android:text="@string/text_placeholder_benefit"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textDefault"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:maxLines = "12"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_benefit"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left">

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textTitulo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Nombre hotel"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**PROBLEM:**

When I need auto height, on the text, whether increases or decreases, I tried Fragment Layout layout_height: wrap_content but text overlap image.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: use relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FrameLayout renders it's children in a stack - one on top of the other unless you use layout_gravity to position them. FrameLayout is typically used with the entire available screen space - the layout_height and layout_width are set to match parent.

Your issue is because you have the layout_height set to wrap content, it will overlay widgets one on top of the other. Set the layout_height to match parent. Or better yet for your case, use a RelativeLayout.